# ignore where clause column when null

Tags: sql

i have one SQL where I want to order it in such clause when one of the ordering clause is NUll, then it should skip it and move to next ordering clause

Comment: Welcome to SO. For questions like this it might be hard for some people to understand what you mean. In SQL related questions it is nearly ALWAYS best to post a "here the data I have got now" and a "here's what I want it to look like when my query is run successfully pair of tables. Please don't post screenshots for data, in case someone wants to test with it

Comment: How can an ordering clause be null? Please show an example. Do you mean a value is null, like in `order by col1, col2` and in some records col1 is null? But well, where should these be ordered then? If you mean this, then also show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: One more thing: When asking SQL questions, you should (almost) always also tag the DBMS you are asking this for (MySQL or SQL Server or Oracle or ...), because the products' SQL dialects differ.

Answer (score 0):

use case when for order

```
order by case when val is not null then yourdeseired
         else val end asc
```

or you can use coalesce

```
order by COALESCE(col1, col2,999999) //here if both column is null then its order value will be 999999 otherwise it will order according to 1st non null column wise
```

Comment: @Nick with respect to you could you please tell me, where you seen copy?

Comment: @Nick can not i use same function if my explanation others person explanation is different ??? totally disagreed with this that you any person can use a function and i will not able to use that function with explanation

Comment: And suddenly someone inserts the value 1000000 and the order by fails...  "Safe" constants used to ensure functionality are a bit unsafe.

Comment: I don't think your explanation is that different. But I'll get off my horse now.

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce, to bring the next ordering clause into the current considering order by column:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY firstcolumn, COALESCE(second_column_might_be_null, thirdcolumn), thirdcolumn
```